# How to find the time when an order was fulfilled?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

When getting the order information form the api we get the fulfilment status but not the exact time when the order was fulfilled. The fulfilment information from the api is missing.

The fulfilment object in an order has the following properties.

```
  fulfillments: [
{
  id: NUMBER,
  admin_graphql_api_id: 'gid://shopify/Fulfillment/NUMBER',
  created_at: '2022-01-04T11:07:59-05:00',
  location_id: NUMBER,
  name: 'STRING',
  order_id: NUMBER,
  receipt: {},
  service: 'manual',
  shipment_status: null,
  status: 'success',
  tracking_company: 'ACME',
  tracking_number: 'NUMBER',
  tracking_numbers: [Array],
  tracking_url: 'https://acme.com/TrackConfirmAction?qtc_tLabels1=NUMBER',
  tracking_urls: [Array],
  updated_at: '2022-01-04T11:08:00-05:00',
  line_items: [Array]
}
```

],

created_at has the information when the fulfilment was created and updated at could have the information when it was even shipped/delivered. How do I get this time, pointers to documentation would be really appreciated.

Comment: The GraphQL documentation is superb for this. Grab your API keys for a store with orders, fire up Insomnia, and within miniutes you will have what you want. Example? 

https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2021-10/objects/FulfillmentOrder#top

Comment: Thank you for the link but it returns the same data as the rest api. Please correct me if I’m wrong.

Comment: I think I found it https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2021-10/objects/FulfillmentEvent#top